# If I summon a world breaker can I exile a card my opponent owns?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I summon [World Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorld%20Breaker%5d) and want to destroy my opponent's land.

But my opponent thinks I should exile one of my own lands, as cost to summon a World Breaker.

Whose lands am I allowed or required to exile in this case?

Comment: Does he ever play a Shock, Doom Blade, Lightning Bolt, etc? Ask him if he thinks that he should have to choose one of his own creatures for the "target creature". Then ask him what wording is different here.

Comment: Hes very bad in english... thats the problem most of the time

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this ability isn't actually a cost. If it were a cost, it would be written as, "As an additional cost to cast World Breaker, exile target artifact, enchantment, or land." Since the ability begins with "When you cast", it's a triggered ability. One of the things that this means is that if there are no artifacts, enchantments or lands on the battlefield, you can still cast World Breaker.

Comment: @TannerSwett Even if the card were worded the way you say, you could STILL exile an opponent's permanent instead of your own. Being an "additional cost" doesn't change that at all. Though you're right that it would mean you could only cast it if there were a valid target.

Comment: I don't think additional costs ever use the word "target". The rules might handle it, but it would cause confusion and complication. e.g. _As an additional cost, sacrifice target creature you control. Draw 3 cards._ would be countered on resolution for having no legal targets!

Answer (score 12):

Worldbreaker's cast trigger says:

> When you cast World Breaker, exile target artifact, enchantment, or land.

So, when you cast World Breaker, you pick a target.  It doesn't have to be one of your artifacts, enchantments or lands.

However, for the return ability:

> {2}{C}, Sacrifice a land: Return World Breaker from your graveyard to your hand.

Using that ability would require you to sacrifice one of your own lands (which means putting that land into the graveyard; it won't get exiled).  You can't sacrifice something you don't control (although if you somehow came to control an opponent's land, you could sacrifice it even though you don't own it).

Answer (score -3):

If any effect/ability states "target (insert card type here)", it can be any permanent of that type.